# How to annotate the return type which is related with input Generic type

Tags: python, annotations

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


I = TypeVar("I")
O = TypeVar("O")


class Base(Generic[I, O]):
    def __init__(self, input: I) -> None:
        self.input = input
        
    def convert(self) -> O:
        ...

class ToStr(Base[int, str]): ...
class ToInt(Base[str, int]): ...


def convert(*c: Base) -> *O:  # I don't known how to annotate the return type
    return tuple(c.convert() for c in c)


convert(ToStr(1), ToInt("2"))  # type should be (str, int)
```

I am implementing a generic class, which has input generic type `I` and output generic type `O`.
This class has a convert method, can convert `I` into `O`.

But when I want to define a function to call these class objects, I have no idea how to annotate the return type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've hit the nail on the head here. From what I understand of the `typing` module, I don't believe this is possible currently, unless someone can actually prove otherwise. The reason is that the `Tuple[x, ...]` syntax, which represents a variadic tuple, also known as a [variable-length tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple), actually represents a *homogeneous* collection of elements, similar to a `list` which is annotated as `List[x]` for example.

So ostensibly, this limitation also carries over to the case when we define `T` as a `TypeVar`, and want to annotate the return type as `Tuple[T, ...]`. This unfortunately still means the return type is *homogenous*, and unfortunately it can't vary the element types depending on what the type of `T` is  here, even though it is exactly what we desire in this case.

For example, here's a *mostly* thorough test I did to confirm:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Tuple

I = TypeVar("I")
O = TypeVar("O")


class Base(Generic[I, O]):
    def __init__(self, input: I) -> None:
        self.input = input

    def convert(self) -> O:
        ...


class ToStr(Base[int, str]): ...


class ToInt(Base[str, int]): ...


def convert(*c: Base[I, O]) -> Tuple[O, ...]:  # I don't known how to annotate the return type
    return tuple(c.convert() for c in c)


s = convert(ToStr(1), ToInt("2"))  # type should be (str, int)

# s[1].  # suggestions still show `str` as first one, which is wrong here
```

As you can see, that doesn't work out. The TypeVar `O` is bound to the type of `O` for the first element, `str` in this case.

I think, that unfortunately the closest you can get for type hinting purposes is using the below explicit syntax:

```
tup = ToStr(1).convert(), ToInt('2').convert()
```

This type checks correctly, at least in Pycharm. The IDE correctly infers the type as `tuple[str, int]` in this case. The downside here of course is that it's a bit unwieldy, and the syntax is a bit overly verbose. But it's the best solution I can think of at the moment, that at least does appear to work as desired.